# Strange results when dealing with php mktime and date

Tags: php, strtotime, mktime

I need to generate a delivery time based on a store's opening time plus an offset. The opening time is generated correctly, and the offset is generated correctly, but I can't seem to get them combined correctly. I've tried this several ways:

```
$open = array('open_hr' => 14, 'open_min' => 0);

$tmpTime = mktime($open['open_hr'], $open['open_min']);
$openTime = date('G:i', $tmpTime);

$tmpOffset = 90; //in minutes
$tmpOpenWithOffset = $tmpTime + $tmpOffset * 60;
$finalTime = date('G:1', $tmpOpenWithOffset);

echo "open time: " . $openTime . "; offset in minutes: " .$tmpOffset . "; final time: " .$finalTime;
```

The result of this is:

> open time: 14:00; offset in minutes: 90; final time: 15:1

I would expect that adding 90 minutes to 14:00 would result in 15:30.

I've also tried it this way:

```
$open = array('open_hr' => 14, 'open_min' => 0);
$tmpTime = mktime($open['open_hr'], $open['open_min']);
$openTime = date('G:i', $tmpTime);

$tmpOffset = 90;
$finalTime = strtotime('+'.$tmpOffset . ' minutes', $openTime);

echo "open time: " . $openTime . "; offset in minutes: " .$tmpOffset . "; final time: " .$finalTime;
```

This results in:

```
open time: 14:00; offset in minutes: 90; final time: 5414
```

I've also tried using `eval` to evaluate the first param of `strtotime`, like so:

```
$open = array('open_hr' => 14, 'open_min' => 0);
$tmpTime = mktime($open['open_hr'], $open['open_min']);
$openTime = date('G:i', $tmpTime);

$tmpOffset = 90;
$tmpStr = eval('+'.$tmpOffset . ' minutes');
$finalTime = strtotime($tmpStr, $openTime);

echo "open time: " . $openTime . "; offset in minutes: " .$tmpOffset . "; final time: " .$finalTime;
```

This results in:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /t.php(7) : eval()'d code on line 1
open time: 14:00; offset in minutes: 90; final time:
```

Again, the desired result is that adding 90 minutes to 14:00 will return 15:30. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo:

```
$finalTime = date('G:1', $tmpOpenWithOffset);
```

replacing I with 1 should solve your problem when you take the first solution

Comment: That makes no sense. The 'i' parameter indicates minutes with leading zeros (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). The number 1 isn't a valid parameter for `date()`.

Comment: Sorry, I went back and looked at my code. Your response is backwards, but I see what you were saying. I made a typo and need to replace the number 1 I was using with a letter i. And that did indeed fix the issue. Thanks.